# How to fetch only last record by created_at column for each group in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table `events` with columns:

```
create table event
(
    id             bigserial
        primary key,
    created_at     timestamp with time zone default now() not null,
    type           text                                   not null,
    package_id     bigint                                 not null,
    data           jsonb
);
```

I would like to fetch rows by a list of `package_ids` but only the last (latest creation date) row by column `created_at` for each `package_id`. So, for example if I have:

```
   id | created_at                       | type                 | package_id
    1   2022-02-02 14:46:17.906101 +00:00  ACCEPTED_TERMINAL_DPT  215
    2   2022-02-02 14:50:23.740839 +00:00  LOADED_ON_FLIGHT       215
    3   2022-02-02 14:50:49.132368 +00:00  STORAGE_IN_TERMINAL    215
    4   2022-02-02 14:50:57.067934 +00:00  HANDED_OVER_TO_DRIVER  215
    5   2022-02-02 16:20:51.306371 +00:00  CUSTOMS_EXPORT         215
    6   2022-02-02 16:21:45.661580 +00:00  HELD_IN_CUSTOMS        215
    7   2022-02-02 16:36:20.434390 +00:00  CUSTOMS_IMPORT         215
    10  2022-02-03 14:12:39.751217 +00:00  CUSTOMS_EXPORT         241
    11  2022-02-03 14:12:42.979952 +00:00  HANDED_OVER_TO_DRIVER  241
```

From this rows I would like to fetch only 2 rows (these are the rows with the latest creation date for each package id):

```
7   2022-02-02 16:36:20.434390 +00:00  CUSTOMS_IMPORT         215
11  2022-02-03 14:12:42.979952 +00:00  HANDED_OVER_TO_DRIVER  241
```

Something like this obviously won't work:

```
select *
from event
where package_id in (215, 241)
group by created_at
```

So, I wonder what kind of query could give me such a result?

Comment: For each day in a set, you want the row with the latest creation time of day?

Comment: For each package id I would like a row with the latest creation time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort by package_id and descending created_at, apply [Distinct on](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT) in the select.

```
select distinct on (package_id) *
  from event
where package_id in (215, 241)
order by package_id, created_at desc;
```

Sorting descending created_at works because:

> SELECT DISTINCT ON ( expression [, ...] ) keeps only the first row of
> each set of rows where the given expressions ... equal

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you?

```
with events as (
  select 
   *,
   row_number() over (partition by package_id order by created_at desc) as row_number
  from event
  where package_id in (215, 241)
)
select * from events where row_number = 1
```

Comment: intelijj is complaining about this query, I can't even run it in the console query